# Doctrine 2: order XToMany Relation, itself ordered by another Entity on specific attribute

Tags: doctrine-orm, twig, symfony

I have an entity "Menus", which contains several entities "Dishes" (ManyToMany).

The entity "Dish" has an entity "DishType" (ManyToOne).

The entity DishType contains an attribute "displayOrder" (on which I want to set order).

In Twig, I want to make a loop : 
foreach menus, display each dish grouped by "DishType" and itself, ordered by the attribute "displayOrder" of DishType.

In my entity "Menus", I have :

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Dish", inversedBy="menus", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="dish_menus")
 * @ORM\OrderBy({"dishType" = "ASC"})
 */
protected $dishes;
```

But I woud like to have something like

```
@ORM\OrderBy({"dishType.displayOrder" = "ASC"})
```

Is there a way do do that ?

Isn't there a way to add a default order to the whole entity "DishType" like

```
 * @ORM\OrderBy({"displayOrder" = "ASC"})
```

?

Thank you in advance for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Far from ideal, but I do this with a twig extension, I essentially call a filter in twig to sort the children of an entity for me. Create a twig extension with this function (see twig extensions [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/twig_extension.html))

```
 public function orderPosition($arr) {
        $size = count($arr);
        for ($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++) {
            for ($j = 0; $j < $size - 1 - $i; $j++) {
                if ($arr[$j + 1]->getPosition() < $arr[$j]->getPosition()) {
                    $this->swap($arr, $j, $j + 1);
                }
            }
        }
        return $arr;
    }
```

Then call it in twig

```
{%for single in orderPosition($entity->otherEntity) %}
{{single}}
{%endfor%}
```